# Is it possible to run the bigquery editor UI as a service account?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a service account that has access to certain datasets that aren't part of my project. I would like to run some queries on them. I am able to do this from the cloud shell using bq commands, but would it be possible to do this using the big query editor?

Comment: No, it isn't. Service Account is a machine account. Machine use CLI and APIs, not the UI (User Interface). Service account is not for a user, only for a machine!

Comment: Okay, thanks. If you answer I can accept it. FYI in AWS you can assume a role and log in as a role so I thought the concept was similar

Comment: Indeed, assuming a role is a super cool feature to be able to test/validate permissions without switching users or using only the API. You have IAM analyzer that can help you to test and validate permissions, but it's far less poweerfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't. Service Account is a machine account. Machine use CLI and APIs, not the UI (User Interface). Service account is not for a user, only for a machine!